# From Jmeter command line, how to export results of all Controllers except one to CSV

Tags: csv, jmeter

My Thread Group contains "Include Controller" with a reference to jmx and a "Simple Controller" with http requests.

From Command line(Non GUI mode), While I execute,

> I need CSV results to contain results only from "Simple Controller"

OR

> a way to identify response time based on Controller name in the generated CSV

Can you please help - I am passing below code in the command line

```
sh Jmeter.sh -n -t R3Functions.jmx  -l Results/Calendar.csv -J ucount=10
```

From the generated csv, I am finding it very difficult to get the

> response time of http requests only under "Simple Controller"

as it also includes results of http requests from "Include Controller".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing approaches to filter results basing belonging to this or that parent controller so I would recommend just use different labels for the requests originating from main and included .jmx files so you will be able to distinguish them either manually or using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) plugin which can filter sample results basing on regular expression matches of samplers labels (names).

---

You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Filter Results Tool]